# Tkinter error :( Attribute error: 'Entry' has no attribute 'set', 'get'

Tags: python, tkinter, get, set

estoy practicando tkinter, y estoy haciendo un programa que descargue videos, necesito poner si es un audio o un video en el ENTRY pero no me deja usar el metodo get y set:

```
import pytube
from tkinter import *

def ola():
    #no me sirven el get y el set :(
    opciones_texto.set("hola")

ventana = Tk()

ventana.title("Video Downloader")
ventana.resizable(False, False)
ventana.geometry("580x400")
ventana.config(background = "blue")

opciones_label = Label(ventana, bg = "blue", fg = "white", text = "Escribe en que formato vas a descargar el archivo (audio, video): ", font = ("",10,"bold")).place(x=0,y=0)

opciones_texto = Entry(ventana, state = "normal", font = ("",10))
opciones_texto.place(x=425,y=0)

examinar_boton = Button(ventana, width = 10, font = ("",13), command = ola, text = "Examinar").place(x=250,y=30)


ventana.mainloop()
```

Este es el error que me da COMPLETO:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Mi usuario :v\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1885, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/Mi usuario :v/OneDrive/Bibliotecas/Python/CapturadorDePantalla.py", line 6, in ola
    opciones_texto.set("hola")
AttributeError: 'Entry' object has no attribute 'set'
```

Me dice exactamente lo mismo cuando pongo get pero obviamente cambia el 'set' por 'get'

Comment: Bienvenido! Me extraña que ese error te suceda con el método `.get`. Que versión de Python usas?

Comment: Hola dante, uso la 3.9.0, la ultima :)

Comment: Hola Alan :) Yo uso la 3.8.0 y no me sucede ningún fallo con el `.get`. Seguro que te dice exactamente lo mismo o hay una leve diferencia? Usas el `.get` con un Entry?

Comment: Hola, si uso el Entry aunque tal vez use en algun programa el Text, en cuanto al codigo de error, esta exactamente asi, el get y el set no me funcionan :(, no se si es por la version (3.9.0)

Answer (score 0):

el problema es simple, el widget `Entry` no tiene método `set()`. Si modificas tu código de la siguiente manera no tendrás error, esto es por que solo llamamos a `get()`, el cual si existe como método para el widget.

```
def ola():
    print(opciones_texto.get())
```

Ahora, si lo que deseas es fijar una cadena a la `Entry` puedes hacerlo como sigue. (Las lineas con comentario son las que modifiqué)

```
from tkinter import *

def ola():
    #Fijamos lo que el usuario ingresa a la entry
    entryText.set(f'Se escribio: {opciones_texto.get()}')

ventana = Tk()
#Creamos la variable el texto
entryText = StringVar()
#Este texto aparecera en la entry por defecto:
entryText.set('Escriba algo: ')


ventana.title("Video Downloader")
ventana.resizable(False, False)
ventana.geometry("580x400")
ventana.config(background = "blue")

opciones_label = Label(ventana, bg = "blue", fg = "white", text = "Escribe en que formato vas a descargar el archivo (audio, video): ", font = ("",10,"bold"))
opciones_label.place(x=0,y=0)

# Agregamos la opcion 'textvariable' a la entry
opciones_texto = Entry(ventana, state = "normal", font = ("",10), textvariable=entryText) 
opciones_texto.place(x=425,y=0)

examinar_boton = Button(ventana, width = 10, font = ("",13), command = ola, text = "Examinar")
examinar_boton.place(x=250,y=30)

ventana.mainloop()
```

Al iniciar el programa obtienes en la Entry una cadena que dice: `Escriba algo:` .
Si borras eso y escribes en la Entry por ejemplo, "hola", se fija en la Entry: `Se escribio: Hola`

Comment: muchas gracias, no me di cuenta de que el textvariable no lo estaba usando en la funcion :v

Answer (score 0):

en vez de .set, para entry se usa el metodo .insert(siempre con el 0,y el texto, ejeplo 'entry1.insert(0,"texto")'
para el metodo .get fijate lo siguiente, que cuando le pones la linea de ubicacion, ya sea place, pack o grid, lo hagas en una segunda linea. no entiendo porque python no toma eso correctamente, pero siempre hace los widgets en 2 lineas, la de creacion, y la de ubicacion